# How to find which Class is causing OutOfMemory for the JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic, out-of-memory

Oflate our Weblogic server is frequently crashing with OutOfMemory error. Is there any way I can monitor the JVM to find out which Classes are are hogging the memory and have the maximum number of objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes.  The way I did it was to configure the jvm to create a heap dump on OOM, then I pulled the heap down and ran it thru jvisualvm.  You can compute the retained sizes (took a long time) but it will be very clear what the offender is.

You can also attach jvisualvm to a running instance, but you need to configure the jvm to accept the connection.  That way you can watch the heap grow in real time. See this; its for jboss but should be very similar: https://wiki.projectbamboo.org/display/BTECH/VisualVM+Profiler

I think it is easier to get to the answer after you have a heap dump though, as when you watch it in real time things get garbage collected and whatnot.

EDIT -- here are my startup configs.

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps  
-Xloggc:/path/to/memlogs/memlog.txt -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution   
-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m   
-server -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=xxxx   
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false   
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<ip-address> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError   
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/heapdumps/ -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled   
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

because I configured it to drop memory logs, I can tail the memlog.txt file in real time to see what happened.  I can connect to the jvm if I want, but like I said I will just analyze the heap after a crash to see what the issue is, because after the fact its really clear....

Comment: How do you configure JVM to generate heapdump on OOM?

Comment: I guess I need use -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag.

Answer (score 2):

There's [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html) as of JDK 1.5 (or 5.0, if you're into that).

Comment: Unfortunately with JConsole, it doesn't let me see the Classes that are loaded and hogging the most resource. I need that to guess the source of the OOM.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools out there but I use Eclipse's Memory Analysis Toolkit.  You can download it as a standalone tool and it will let you do heap analysis and even connect to a JVM and analyze there.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond JConsole, jRat is one good free-as-in-beer profiler, YourKit is another great commercial product.

Answer (score 0):

From some other Questions I came to know about jhat and jmap. These are already available in JDK packages. Also the below link provides a good list on which tool to use in which scenarios:-

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/